# Not able to start the system after executing halt command

Tags: 14.04, putty

I executed halt command in my ubuntu system to shut it down. Now, I am unable to  start the system using putty and its displaying "Network error: Connection timed out". I tried to ssh from other system only to get "No route to host" message. I even pinged and it said Destination host unreachable. Please help...

Comment: Have you tried to power on the ubuntu system again ?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly stated, you did a shutdown on your machine. This means no connection over network (maybe you have possibillity for WakeOnLAN), so you have to power your machine on again and after the boot you should be able to reach it.